# RSpec: should_receive as thing being spec-ed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, testing, rspec

I'd like to use `should_receive` as the subject of a spec in RSpec. In other words, instead of testing a `should ==`, I'd like to test that another class receives a method call.

What I'd like to write is something like:

```
describe '#methodOne' do

  subject { ClassTwo }

  it { should_receive(:methodTwo) }

  ClassOne.methodOne

end
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's how I did it:

```
describe "#methodOne" do

  it "calls the appropriate method" do

    ClassTwo.should_receive(:methodTwo)
    ClassOne.methodOne

  end

end
```

This works beautifully

Answer (score 3):

There are ways you can contort RSpec to do things like this but it's not using RSpec how it's intended.  `should_receive` sets up a mock expectation that a method will be called.  It doesn't make sense for the one liner `it` syntax.

I recommend you start with the basic `describe`/`it` structure and only refactor to the more advanced constructs (subject, one-line `it`) when you've got duplication.

Comment: How could I rewrite my code, so that it tests the `should_receive`, in a way that RSpec is intended for?

Answer (score -1):

I would use the subject in its instance variable form:

```
@subject.should_receive(:methodTwo)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It skips the spec, like nothing is being tested.

Comment: Aye, you should be mocking your subject class and using `should_receive` on it, as this is part of the RSpec::Mocks library. [Here](http://ivolo.us/posts/rspec-tutorial-part-4-mocking) is a good tutorial if you need it.